# Android Camera2 preview occasionally rotated by 90 degrees

Tags: android, rotation, android-camera2

I'm working on some app using Android's Camera2 API. So far I've been able to get a preview displayed within a `TextureView`. The app is by default in landscape mode. When using the emulator the preview will appear upside-down. On my physical Nexus 5 the preview is *usually* displayed correctly (landscape, not upside-down), but occasionally it is rotated by 90 degrees, yet stretched to the dimensions of the screen.
I thought that should be easy and thought the following code would return the necessary information on the current orientation:

```
// display rotation
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
// sensor orientation
mManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId).get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```

... I was pretty surprised when I saw that above code **always** returned `1` for the display rotation and `90` for the sensor orientation, *regardless* of the preview being rotated by 90 degree or not. (Within the emulator sensor orientation is always 270 which kinda makes sense if I assume 90 to be the correct orientation).
I also checked the width and height within `onMeasure` within [AutoMeasureTextureView](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.java) (adopted from [Android's Camera2 example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java)) that I'm using to create my TextureView. But no luck either - width and height reported from within `onMeasure` are always the same regardless of the preview rotation.
So I'm clueless on how to tackle this issue. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for the occasional hickups in my preview orientation?

[Edit]
A detail I just found out: Whenever the preview appears rotated `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged` in the `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` seems not to get called. In the documentation for `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged` it is said that this method is called whenever the `SurfaceTexture`'s buffers size is changed. I have a method `createCameraPreviewSession` (copied from Android's Camera2 example) in which I set the default buffer size of my texture like

```
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
```

From my logging output I can tell that `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged` is called exactly after that - however, not always... (or setting the default buffer size sometimes silently fails?).

Answer (score 4):

I think I can answer my own question: I was creating my Camera2 Fragment after the [Android's Camera2 example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java). However, I didn't really consider the method `configureTransform` to be important as, opposite to the example code, my application is forced to landscape mode anyway. It turned out that this assumption was wrong. Since having `configureTransform` reintegrated in my code I haven't experienced any more hiccups.

Update: The original example within the Android documentation pages doesn't seem to exist anymore. I've updated the link which is now pointing to the code on Github.

Comment: Hi, @5tefan. Sorry, your link is a little bit broken )

Comment: Oh, things change (from time to time). That link used to work but Google seems to have moved the page or deleted it... sorry.

Comment: @5tefan perhaps you would care searching for the link that works now, so your answer is still useful to others :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus I think the example no longer exits within Google's developer documentation. However, I meanwhile found the example on Github (I think it's the same example as the one I linked to in the first place). I'm sorry if I can't take care of links in my posts that once worked and are broken now - it's Google who's responsible of breaking that link...

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced a similar issue on the Nexus device. The below code is working for me.
Call this function before opening the camera and also on Resume().

```
private void transformImage(int width, int height) 
{

    if (textureView == null) {

        return;
    } else try {
        {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
            RectF previewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, textureView.getHeight(), textureView.getWidth());
            float centerX = textureRectF.centerX();
            float centerY = textureRectF.centerY();
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(), centerY - previewRectF.centerY());
                matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF, previewRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                float scale = Math.max((float) width / width, (float) height / width);
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
                matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
            }
            textureView.setTransform(matrix);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this different from Stefan's own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506843/192373)?

Comment: what about SurfaceTexture, I don't have TextureView or SurfaceView

Answer (score 1):

I followed the whole `textureView.setTransform(matrix)` method listed above, and it worked.  However, I was also able to manually set the rotation using the much simpler `textureView.setRotation(270)` without the need to create a `Matrix`.

Comment: That worked fine for your particular test device(s). Please don't assume it'll work fine on all of them; there's some possible variation on how the image sensor is attached to the device, so different cameras need different amounts of rotation applied.

Comment: @EddyTalvala: do you refer to hard-coding 270° or to using **View.setRotation()** instead of **setTransform(Matrix )** ?