# Android Camera2 API, how does one get the preview image to cover the whole screen using transformation matrices?

Tags: android, matrix, camera, transform, orientation

Consider the following code:

```
        @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        if (rotation != prevRotation) {
            int angle = ORIENTATIONS_REAL.get(rotation);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Rotation = " + angle);
            if (angle == 90 || angle == 270) {
                angle = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
                float centerX = cameraRectF.centerX();
                float centerY = cameraRectF.centerY();
                int rotAngle = (angle + sensorOrientation + 180) % 360; // Formula correct
                transformMatrix.postRotate(rotAngle, centerX, centerY);
            } else {
                transformMatrix.reset();
            }
            textureView.setTransform(transformMatrix);
            prevRotation = rotation;
        }
    }
```

Here's some of the definitions:

```
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS_REAL = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
}

private Size imageDimensions = null;
private Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();
private RectF previewRectF = null;
private RectF cameraRectF = null;
private int sensorOrientation = 0;

private TextureView textureView = null;
private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = null;
private Button buttonTakePicture = null;

// Some misc stuff
private int prevRotation = 0;
```

Note that sensorOrientation is set when from CameraCharacteristics in the opening routine.

I was having fits trying to get the orientation to display correctly on a Samsung Galaxy S7.  Turns out that the sensor is rotated 90° from the handset.  The above code takes into account the reported sensor orientation and computes the correct rotation angle needed.  Now the problem is that when the handset is rotated from portrait to landscape, the camera preview image does not cover the entire screen.  See the screenshots below.

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]

So now the question is how do I get the camera preview to cover the screen instead of just one segment of it?  The above code was adapted from an answer here:

[Android Camera2 preview occasionally rotated by 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460985/android-camera2-preview-occasionally-rotated-by-90-degrees)

However, I don't have the second set of width and height to use and I'm not sure where to get them.  What I have tried though was take the camera resolution and map it over, but that failed quite spectacularly. Part of the problem is that I am not all that familiar with transforms and how they work.  I understand they are generally handled by matrices with lots of matrix math, but I haven't seen or even played with code like this for some time (Last time was in a class 2 years ago.) Thoughts? Advise?

Thanks.

EDIT: I expect the app to be used more or less in portrait mode, but I have to handle landscape mode in case the user rotates the device.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I ended up answering my own question.  Originally, I started with the answer from [Android Camera2 preview occasionally rotated by 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460985/android-camera2-preview-occasionally-rotated-by-90-degrees).  This code has a bug in it.  Specifically the scaling.  With that, and a few other changes, I was able to get it to work.  The linked answer said to put the call right before you open the camera, which I did originally.  So what would happen is that when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape (or vice-versa), the system would restart the activity.  However, if you quickly flipped the device so it was still in landscape but upside down, then the image would appear to be rotated out by 180° because the final rotation is still landscape and the system doesn't restart the activity.  So placing the code inside the surface changed callback routine guarantees that the code will be called any time the orientation changes, whether the activity is restarted or not.

Here's the revised code:

```
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            if (rotation != prevRotation) {
            prevRotation = rotation;
            RectF cameraRectF = new RectF(0, 0, imageDimensions.getWidth(), imageDimensions.getHeight());
            RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0, 0, textureView.getHeight(), textureView.getWidth());
            float centerX = cameraRectF.centerX();
            float centerY = cameraRectF.centerY();
            if (rotation != Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                textureRectF.offset(centerX - textureRectF.centerX(), centerY - textureRectF.centerY());
                transformMatrix.setRectToRect(cameraRectF, textureRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                float scale = Math.max(
                        (float) textureRectF.right / cameraRectF.right,
                        (float) textureRectF.bottom / cameraRectF.bottom);
                transformMatrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
                if (rotation != Surface.ROTATION_180) {
                    int angle = (ORIENTATIONS_REAL.get(rotation) + sensorOrientation +
                            ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR.get(sensorOrientation)) % 360;
                    transformMatrix.postRotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
                } else {
                    transformMatrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
                }
            } else {
                transformMatrix.reset();
            }
        }
        textureView.setTransform(transformMatrix);
    }
```

My code also takes into account the sensor orientation as well, so it should work on any device.  I have three different devices, two of which report that the sensor orientation is 90°.  The third device reports the sensor orientation as being 0°.  Therefore, with a bit of experimentation, I came up with a table that will add a constant to the final rotation angle based on what the sensor rotation angle is.  Below are the definitions for the orientations.  ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR is the afore mentioned table.

```
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS_REAL = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
    ORIENTATIONS_REAL.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
}
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR.append(0, 180);
    ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR.append(90, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR.append(180, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS_SENSOR.append(270, -90);
}
```

Although I was only able to test 0° and 90° from the table, I invite others who have devices with reported sensor orientations of 180° and 270° to verify that my calculations are correct.

Comment: do you have a github with this example?